# android.view.InflateException: Error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is my standalone_example.xml
on compilation it throws an error of Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class
can some one help me out where am i going wrong with this .xml, as the first activity is working properly I am not posting that .and this is the other .xml.

Moreover this is the path where the PageCurlView.java is located

com\example\rustomjeeelementsupperjuhu.PageCurlView.java

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <com.example.rustomjeeelementsupperjuhu.PageCurlView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/dcgpagecurlPageCurlView1"
            android:background="@drawable/page1">
        </com.example.rustomjeeelementsupperjuhu.PageCurlView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show `PageCurlView` also under which package is it?

Comment: ca not put the whole file total characters exceed than the given.

Comment: give complete path of the PageCurlView or may be error in PageCurlView,Post the code for good suggestion

Comment: this is the git hub link where it is located

https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl